# @input two-way binding does not work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to access the text I have in a text area in my child component to put it on the parent component and keep it updated.

I was told that @input in angular 4 is supposed to perform two-way binding. But I can't do that that way, and I don't understand why.

I found a workaround for this issue. It includes an @Output to send the info to the parent component. But if Input already does that (in some way I don't know), I want to avoid it.

For example, this is my Parent Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-settings',
    templateUrl: './settings.component.html',
})
export class SettingsComponent {

    private studyDesignText =  'Text';

    constructor() {
    }

    public handleStudyDesignUpdated(designText: any) {
        this.studyDesignText = designText;
    }

}
```

It's html

```
<div class="section section-trials-settings-parent light rounded">
  <div class="section section-trials-settings-child">
    <div class="pure-g">
      <div class="pure-u-1-1">
        <app-settings-study-design
          [studyDesignText]="studyDesignText">
        </app-settings-study-design>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My child component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-settings-study-design',
  templateUrl: './settings-study-design.component.html',
})
export class SettingsStudyDesignComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() studyDesignText: string;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    super.onInit();
    loadControls();
  }

  loadControls(): void {
    this.startAllTextAreas();
  }

  private startAllTextAreas() {
    this.startTextArea('study-design-textarea');
  }

  private startTextArea(htmlId: string) {
    // code to configure my text area; it's right...

}
```

If I change the value in the text area and send a signal with @Output so my parent component can be notified and console log the value, the printed value is the initial one. My friend did the same thing and it worked.

What am I missing?

Comment: you need an `EvenEmitter<string>` and use the same event handler in your parent

Comment: The idea is to avoid using EventEmitter. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Input()` is always one way binding from `parent->child`. Two way binding happens in this case, only when you have `object` as an input property. This is because, the reference for objects remain the same. And when one of the object updates, the other will also get updated. This is not true for `string` or `number`. It is always one way binding.

Comment: I'm getting it now. My friend was using an object and it was doing the job for him. As I need to keep track with a string, it doesn't work. Nice.

So, I need to use @Output decorator to make the whole wheel?

Comment: Yes, you are right here. For types other than Object, you have to use `@Output()` along with `EventEmitter()`

Comment: yes you have to use @Output to pass data from child to parent along with EventEmitter as i told before